# Emulate Raspberry Pi architecture on a personal computer

Tags: linux, virtualbox, raspberry-pi, arm, x86

Is there a way to create a virtual ARM architecture machine so that I could create Raspberry Pi images on my PC?

For instance, I would like to create an Ubuntu Server 17.04 image that I could burn to an SD card an then boot an RPi 3. I'm assuming that if I create the image in virtualbox on x86 architecture then it won't run on the RPi hardware.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I will give you a hint: `qemu`.

Comment: I've seen articles referring to running rpi software in qemu, but I thought qemu was "just" a VM like virtualbox. But sounds like it can do something different.

Comment: Unlike Virtualbox, qemu can emulate other kind CPUs than x86.

Comment: QEMU based: "Raspberry Pi Emulator
A Raspberry Pi emulator for Mac OS X and Linux"
SourceForge : https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspberrypiemulator/files/?source=navbar